# Read from a file using getc and print using putc

Tags: c, file, file-io, getc

I'm trying to read each character from a file and print it to the screen using getc and putc alone. Here's my code,

```
FILE *fp = fopen("new.txt","r+");
rewind(fp);
while( feof(fp) == 0 )
{
      putc( getc(fp) , stdout);
}
```

When ever I execute this, it runs into an infinite loop. I can't understand how this happens when the file is only a few lines long.

Newbie.

Comment: You might to want to read a [reference on `fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen), as that code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: "while feof" is wrong. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Why link to cppreference ?

Comment: Please copy and paste exactly the code you compiled and tried. The code in your question, with r+, does not even compile. Also, show a complete example, not just the part that you think is the problem.

Comment: @cnicutar They have both a [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) *and* a [C reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c).

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy while you're right of course, surely you're aware that he's opening the file with mode `"r+"`... if he provided the exact code in this case, you wouldn't have any new details and you already have enough information in what you've looked at to understand the cause of the problem.

Comment: @mah: Yes, I agree that it is very likely that he is opening the file with "r+", But I _don't_ understand the cause of the problem. (The feof thing doesn't cause an infinite loop.) Since the code in the question has _one_ obvious error that shows that it can't be the actual code he runs, isn't it reasonable to suspect that there might be other, more crucial, differences?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looping while `feof` returns zero is almost *never* correct.

Instead you might want to read from the input *and* check that the input function didn't fail in one expression:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    putc(ch, stdout);
```

This reads a character using `getc`, checks that the reading was successful by comparing the character against `EOF`, and if it's not `EOF` then continue the loop.

Besides, there's no use in calling `rewind` immediately after opening the file, the file is already "rewound".

Answer (score 0):

use the following program for your answer.use `fgetc()` to get the character from file and use `printf()` function to print the character to screen.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char c;
    clrscr();
    fp=fopen("new.txt","r+");
    c=fgetc(fp);
    while(c!=EOF)
    {
        printf("%c",c);
        c=fgetc(fp);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Note that [`fgetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an `int`. This is important for the `EOF` check.